# Deleting memory allocated by repeated fields

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I  currently have something like this in my proto file:

```
message MsgA
{
required string symbol = 1 ;
optional int32  freq = 2   [default = 0]; 
}

message MsgB
{
repeated MsgA val = 1 ;
}
```

Now I know that in order to use the repeated field in `MsgB`. I need to do something like this:

```
MsgB inst;
MsgA some_val = Get_MsgA_Result();
MsgA* res = inst.add_val();
*res = some_val;
```

Now my question is once we are done with MsgB how do we reclaim the memory allocated by `inst.add_val();` ?

Comment: As far as I know, message objects manage their own memory, so there's nothing for you to do.

Comment: So does this mean that once `inst` in the above example gets out of scope.It will also delete the heap instances it allocated with the called `add_val` ?

Comment: Yes. For a quick and dirty test you can just run this through Valgrind and confirm. You could also check in the source code, but I'm fairly sure this is the only way it can possibly make sense.